# If-Else Statements with OR in R

Tags: r, if-statement, probability

Is it possible to change an if-else statement to include OR in an R-Script? Like 70% of the time would turn into this, while the remaining 30% would turn into something else. Similar to increasing the probability to change?

```
if (w0[i, j] == 1) { w1[i, j] <- rL[nNeigh + 1]
        } else             { w1[i, j] <- rD[nNeigh + 1] }
```

This is the statement where the result is deterministic, but I want to change it into a probabilistic function.

```
if (w0[i, j] == 1) { w1[i, j] <- rL[nNeigh + 1] || w1[i, j] <- rL[nNeigh]
        } else             { w1[i, j] <- rD[nNeigh + 1] || w1[i, j] <- rL[nNeigh] }
```

I know this is not the right way to even do it, but I'm at a loss

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick idea:

```r
coin <- rbinom(1, 1, 0.3)

if (w0[i, j] == 1) { 
  w1[i, j] <- coin * rL[nNeigh + 1] + (1 - coin) * rL[nNeigh]
} else {
  w1[i, j] <- coin * rD[nNeigh + 1] + (1 - coin) * rL[nNeigh] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the larger context of the question is.  However note that Martin Gal's useful answer can be simplified:

```
coin <- rbinom(1, 1, 0.3)

if (w0[i, j] == 1) { 
  w1[i, j] <- rL[nNeigh + coin]
} else {
  w1[i, j] <- rD[nNeigh + coin] 
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's obviously a smarter solution.